# Unable to find vcvarsall.bat in python 3.4 and vs 2015

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015

I program with python 3.4 and vs 2015.
When I want to add numpy to vs 2015 in pip window I see fllow problem.
"Unable to find vcvarsall.bat"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat?rq=1

Comment: related to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'anaconda' for install many typical packages.
after run your program wihtout error.